# Angular Directive in Jade

Tags: angularjs-directive, pug

I have an AngularJS's directive, and calling it in Jade Template by using:

`input(auto-complete, ui-items='merchants.name', ng-model='selected')`

I need to have `auto-complete` as it is (without = sign), but it's HTML is shown as

`<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="selected" ui-items="merchants.name" auto-complete="auto-complete">`

How can I eliminate `="auto-complete"` ?

Answer (score 6):

Just hit this too. Everything seems good when you have `doctype html` at the beginning of the `.jade` file.

If you cannot add that to the file (when it's a partial html, etc.), pass `{doctype: 'html'}` as option when you call Jade:

```
jade -O "{doctype:'html'}" partial.jade
```

Answer (score 5):

quoted from *[How can I add an attribute without a value?](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/370)*

> I did find that null removes the attribute and an empty string
>   provides the desired result. So
>   script(src="/javascripts/angular-0.9.19.js",ng:autobind="") works. I
>   didn't see this in the documentation, but it makes sense.

```
input(auto-complete="", ui-items='merchants.name', ng-model='selected')
```